# How to play a float format with 24k sample rate wave via alsa dmix plugin?

Tags: alsa

When I tried to play a float format wave with 24k sample rate via alsa dmix plugin, I got an error message as below:

```
aplay /dev/urandom -r24000 -ffloat_le -v -Dplug:dmix
Playing raw data '/dev/urandom' : Float 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 24000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1145: Unable to install hw params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  FLOAT_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 32
FRAME_BITS: 32
CHANNELS: 1
RATE: 24000
PERIOD_TIME: (21333 21334)
PERIOD_SIZE: NONE
PERIOD_BYTES: (2044 2048)
PERIODS: NONE
BUFFER_TIME: (341333 341334)
BUFFER_SIZE: 8192
BUFFER_BYTES: 32768
TICK_TIME: 0
```

There are some relationships with "float", "24k" and dmix. Is it a known issue of alsa?
Would you please help me about it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `alsa-lib`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried it on a embedded system with alsa-lib 1.0.27, and also tried it in ubuntu 12.04 with alsa-lib 1.0.25.